# How to join two collections in one single MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have one model called `Param` and it has relation with other model called `Port`. When I populate `Param` model, I get access to all `Port` properties. It has many properties but I will point out only those that are necessary:

```
//Port 
{
 username: 123556,
 rxm_name: 'Name #2'
}
```

There is also another, unrelated collection called `Report`, which has the following properties:

```
//Report 
{
  username: 123556,
  box_number: 4423 
}
```

It is worth mentioning, that there are almost 900.000 documents inside `Report` collection.
`box_number` is not unique, but `username` is. Also, there may be some `username`-s from `Port` that exist in `Report` collection.

I used an aggregate function to count all different unique `box_number`-s. This will get amount of `username`-s for each `box_number`:

```
const totalUsers = await Report.aggregate([{
            "$group": {
                _id: {
                    "box_number": "$box_number",
                },
                count: {
                    $sum: 1
                }
            }
        }]);
```

This query returns the following:

```
[
 {
   _id: {
      box_number: 38032
   }, 
   count: 273
 },
 // and so on..
]
```

Now I must perform a query to link `username`,`rxm_name` and `box_number`. Basically, I must show how many `username`-s are in each `box_number` and group them by `rxm_name`. I am stuck for hours, but I am not able to think of such query.  Are there any points that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need $lookup to link 2 collections into one single aggregate command. Here's the aggregate you can use:

```
db.Report.aggregate([
   {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "Port",
         localField: "username",
         foreignField: "username",
         as: "Report2"
       }
  },
{ $unwind : "$Report2" },
{
       $group:
         {
           _id: { box_number: "$box_number", username: "$username" },
           count: {
                    $sum: 1
           },
           rxm_name: { $addToSet: "$Report2.rxm_name" }
         }
}
])
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using different route, but you pointed me in the right direction!